# Status Code: 415 Unsupported Media Type in MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I seen this error for the first time in my practice.My project is .Net Core 2.1 MVC.The error is thrown when I try to login.There are nothning special.Simple AccountController and login form like ussual.
The Error: Status Code: 415; Unsupported Media Type
Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromForm]LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(loginViewModel);
        }

        IdentityUser user = null;

        if (loginViewModel.EmailOrUsername.Contains("@"))
        {
            user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(loginViewModel.EmailOrUsername);
        }
        else
        {
            user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(loginViewModel.EmailOrUsername);
        }

        if (user != null)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, loginViewModel.Password, false, false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return Redirect(loginViewModel.ReturnUrl ?? "/");
            }
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Username or Password");
        return View(loginViewModel);
    }
```

Form:

```
<form asp-action="login" asp-controller="account" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="ReturnUrl" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="EmailOrUsername"></label>
            <input asp-for="EmailOrUsername" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="EmailOrUsername"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Password"></label>
            <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Password"></span>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn buy-now-btn">Login</button>
        <a asp-action="register" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" class="float-right">Don't have an account? Register here!</a>
    </form>
```

And finaly Model:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email/Username")]
    public string EmailOrUsername { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's working fine. Are you trying it from Postman?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add Content-Type Header to your request

Answer (score 0):

You need to add get method for Login

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}
```